# Bootstrap Datepicker dynamic form field add and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have seen many examples about adding and removing normal text fields. BUt on date picker i got the problem.

I have these codes to choose the date.

I want to add more than one date so how i can new date fields dynamicly. And also remove. There are manye xamples only for adding.

```
<div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Dates</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">

                                                <input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium date-picker" size="16" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="help-block">Choose a date </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <div class="input-group">

                                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="plus" class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="add">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </button>
          </span>

                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

I got these code which is working for normal text field dynamic adding.

```
var template = '<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control"/></div>',
    minusButton = '<span class="btn input-group-addon delete-field">(-)</span>';

$('.add-field').click(function() {
  var temp = $(template).insertBefore('.help-block');
  temp.append(minusButton);
});

$('.fields').on('click', '.delete-field', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I am using bootstrap date picker and bootsrap version is 3.3.6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach `datepicker` to the element after inserting it to the DOM.

```
$('.add-field').click(function() {
  var temp = $(template).insertBefore('.help-block');
  temp.find("input[type=text]").datetimepicker();
  temp.append(minusButton);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. i used datepicker instead of datetimepicker. And datepicker is closing automaticly after selecting the date in seconds, thirds etc.